# Measurability of the set of differentiable function in the borel sigma algebra of the continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory

I was studying stochastic calculus and it came up this question of measurability:

Let $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ be the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the uniform topology and his borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

Is the set $\{f\in \mathcal{C}: f \text{ is differentiable} \}$ in $\mathcal{B}$?

Is the set $\mathcal{C}^1([0,1]) $in $\mathcal{B}$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The set of differentiable functions [is not Borel](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm27/fm27121.pdf), as has bee shown by Mazurkiewicz in 1936. It is, however, coanalytic. For a reference in English, see section 33.D in *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Kechris.